# WeakReference, WeakEvents: Usefulness for dynamically loaded/unloaded server modules, DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I am thinking whether the WeakReferences and WeakEvents are suitable in case of server modules interface. Could it be a good design?

But question also performance, there is certainly need for Invoke in WeakEvent pattern and accessing WeakReference, perhaps too

UPDATE:  details

SERVER:

- has module manager,
- can load/unload DLL's implementing classes with shared interface, IModule,
- so module manager creates and keeps instances of IModule,

Modules:

- have a name or a unique code,
- need to interact with other modules, use theirs methods, properties, events,

The issue is that when a module gets an instance of another module(provided by name for example from module manager), then from that point there is no guarantee that the module  could be ever garbage collected before unload.

But there could be a generic class(WeakRefModule where T: IModule) of given IModule implementation, constrained to IModule, which could internally store WeakReference on IModule. And then given module would expose its public methods through extensions methods or inheritance based on WeakRefModule. Hiding instance of the module behind WeakReference.   Same with properties and events(WeakEvents).

Such modules would always guarantee, that other module could not prevent it from garbage collection.

So the question is, how much is it a good design and if there could be some hidden issues?

Comment: Are you OK with the GC randomly deleting event subscriptions and "modules"?

Comment: Why randomly deleting? Modules usually have one instance stored in the  module manager, so a module exists unless explicitly unloaded.

WeakEvents between such modules would not lose subscription unless some modules would be unloaded.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. You have not detailed your architecture. What kind of "modules" are you  talking about?

Comment: Oh sorry, the issue is,t hat when I go to details, usually my questions are closed as not an question, so I avoided that:). I will update the question itself with more details...

Comment: Yeah, that really is necessary. Very abstract right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That design basically works. You need to ensure that there is a strong reference to modules that you want to keep loaded. Otherwise the GC will non-deterministically kill weak references.

One problem is that modules cannot rely on other modules being there. If a module is unloaded and the weak ref turns null calls to that module will either fail or do nothing. Also, the point in time at which the ref turns null is non-deterministic.

I would not use weak references here at all. You can create a wrapper IModule that merely delegates to another IModule. Then you can clear that wrapper when you want to unload a module.

```
class WrappedModule : IModule {
 IModule inner;

 public void Dispose() { inner = null; }

 void IModule.SomeMeth() {
  if (inner == null) throw ...;
  else inner.SomeMeth();
 }
}
```

Now you might leak a wrapper object but it is small. You will not lead the real module.

Modules never get access to other modules directly. Instead, they are passed this "handle" class. The handle can be disabled at any time.